# How can I roll back Firefox back to previous version?

Tags: apt, package-management, firefox, package

After doing a dist-upgrade Firefox got updated to the latest version, how can I go back to the previous version?

Answer (score 2):

Install Synaptic Package Manager

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

launch the program and search for firefox

select it, then select Package at the top

select Force Version...

from the pull down select the version you want

click Apply

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if ***Sean Patterson***'s answer is enough to prevent it from being updated by the AppCenter in the future.

Hence, I'd also mark the package as held back using ‘apt-mark’ command in terminal with root privileges.

For example, making your package say ***Firefox*** unavailable for install, up-gradation or uninstall, type:

**apt-mark hold firefox**

To make this package available for update, just replace ‘hold‘ with ‘unhold‘.

**apt-mark unhold firefox**

[Source](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-lock-blacklist-package-updates-ubuntu-debian-apt/)

Comment: Note: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/544

Comment: Good call. I forgot about locking the version.